# Building my projects makes it copy itself

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a weird problem. I am using `IntelliJ` Idea.

I recently migrated my project to maven but since then every time I build my project it creates a "target" folder and copies the whole project folder inside this. If I build it again it will copy it inside this duplicate folder and so on. At some point, this folder was 2 GB and the compilation took several minutes.

I do not have anything other than my dependencies and maven-compiler-plugin inside my pom file and I did not change any other settings(as far as I remember)

Comment: Looks like you have the root directory of your project marked as a resource root.

Comment: Without the POM file only thing we can do here is guess. And guess by @yole is very likely to be true. And one more question: I understand you synchronize your project and then build it using IDEA's model? Then the issue occurs? Or does it occur as well when building with Maven alone?

Comment: @jannis It happens when I build it using IDEA.

Comment: Please share the relevant `maven-compiler-plugin` configuration or the complete pom.xml file.